# Insufficient Privilege's on Contact

Tags: account, sharing, contact, insufficient-privileges

I have a contact that is acting like it's a private Contact even though it's related to an Account.
Users are able to access the Account without any issues, but the Contact continues to give an Insufficient Privilege's error.

The Users have Read, Create, Edit, and View All on both Contacts and Accounts, and the sharing settings have Accounts as Public Read/Write with the Contact being controlled by its parent.

Any ideas why this error might continue to appear?

Comment: any Restriction Rules in place?

Comment: @cropredy no none at all...

Answer (score 1):

You see the Insufficient Privileges error if you don’t have the right access on different levels. For example, your profile prevents you from accessing the account object, or your role prevents you from accessing a case record. You also see an Insufficient Privileges error when you click a link to a record or a Visualforce page tab to which you don’t have access.

Record owners can resolve most cases by using the Sharing button on the record detail page, which enables them to share the record to another user. Salesforce admins can also resolve this issue using the API, such as querying the UserRecordAccess object to check a user’s access to a set of records. For more information, see the SOAP API Developer Guide.

If these tools can’t help you resolve the issue, your Salesforce org’s admin can try to diagnose it with this troubleshooting flow.

[Resolve object-level access errors by reviewing the user profiles and permission sets.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=admin_insufficient_privileges_object.htm&type=5&language=en_US)

[Resolve Record-Level Access Errors](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=admin_insufficient_privileges_record.htm&type=5&language=en_US)

[Resolve process-level errors by reviewing validation rules and Apex triggers.](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=admin_insufficient_privileges_process.htm&type=5&language=en_US)

[How to Deal with the Salesforce Insufficient Privileges Error](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2014/how-to-deal-with-the-salesforce-insufficient-privileges-error)

Comment: Very thorough answer! Unfortunately it was not of much help. The articles listed go largely over what I've already mentioned regarding the object level permissions and sharing. I did take your advice and look at the UserRecordAccess object, which says the user should have read, edit, and transfer access even though they're still getting the insufficient privileges error.